# wordpress loop, applying something new every third post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this loop which basically displays a block on the page with an image in it, the class `gallerypic` has a margin of 20px on the right, it also has the rule `float:left;`, the issue is every time the third div is created it starts on a new line, because the margin is pushing it there. So Ideally every third post I would like no margin, and to apply a div `gallerypicright` or something.

Im wondering does someone have a solution to this? Possibly an easier one that simply stops the margin from happening when its the third one? I need the margin on the other two as it creates a neat gap between the posts.

```
<?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=14&showposts=14&paged=' . $paged);
            $id = get_the_ID();

while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>

                     <div class="events">
        <div class="gallerypic"><div class="limerickguideblockheader"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="gallerypiccontainer"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'gallery-thumb', $attr ); ?> </a></div>
         </div> 
  </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

edit: a picture paints a 1000 words, here is the link so far, with three posts...
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/?page_id=2466

A method via CSS would be even better if possible.
Cheers
Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
<style>
.gallerypicright {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
...
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); 
  $count++;
  $third_div = ($count%3 == 0) ? 'gallerypicright' : '';
?>
...
<div class="gallerypic <?php echo $third_div; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks air4x, that makes sense but im getting an error  unexpected ';' in /var/www/dev_limerickfc/cms/wp-content/themes/limerickfc/category-14.php on line 98, is the line where `$third_div` is created correct syntax? Apologies as im still only learning php

Comment: Sorry, replace the second `?` by `:`. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure CSS solution, you could try using

```
.gallerypic:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    margin:0;
}
```

`n` is a counter that goes up for every element. The counter (`n`) starts at `0` but the elements on the page start at `1`, so the `3n + 1` means for every `3 * n + 1` elements, e.g.:

element **1** (3 * 0 + 1), **4** (3 * 1 + 1), **7** (3 * 2 + 1) etc.

This solution is only available in CSS3, so older browsers won't have it. (see: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child).

Note that `:nth-child` counts all children, so you should group the events in a div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallerypic">...</div>
    <div class="gallerypic">...</div>
    <div class="gallerypic">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to count your post after that in loop you have to module by 3 to total no of post & apply the right class in given post such as

if ($cnt%3 == 0){ $class = 'right'}

Answer (score 0):

You might try the trick of adding a balancing negative right margin on your container, so in your case, perhaps

```
div.events { margin-right: -20px; }
```

Or, if you can cope with the slightly patchy browser support (IE9+ only, better in other browsers, I think) perhaps style using nth-child:

```
.gallerypic:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-right: 0px; }
```